# What is it called when several conditional code blocks are inside each other?

Tags: c#

I cant for the life of me remember what the word is. It's when you ???? several if/else/for/while/usings inside each other.

```
bool isTrue = true, isFalse = true, HasForgottenWord = true;

if( isTrue )
{
   if( isFalse )
   {
       if( HasForgottenWord )
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Ask on StackOverflow.com - kthx bye");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Jeff Attwood has written a nice little blog post about what he calls "Arrow Code" and suggests some nice ideas on how to combat it: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000486.html

Comment: To close voters: This question is not too broad. It is not unclear. What the OP is asking for is just the term used to describe this code-pattern. They even provide a code example showing what they are interested in. It's not a great question. It's quite basic. But, it's neither too broad nor unclear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called nesting

Answer (score 4):

Its called "nesting" them :)

Answer (score 4):

nested maybe what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think nesting might be what he's looking for...

Answer (score 1):

... right: It's called nesting and deep nesting is generally considered a code smell.

Loop block nesting can be reduced by the Linus-Torvalds-Trick (see [Mono Coding Guidelines](http://www.mono-project.com/Coding_Guidelines#Indentation)).

Comment: why did this get a downvote? it answers the question and provides additional information.

Answer (score 1):

It is called as nesting loops